# Invoke method with generic argument using Object argument

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to make some RessourceManager in a light 2D game engine. I want to have a RessourceManager like this :

```
package com.Arsleust.DayumCorp.DayumEngine.Ressource;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class RessourceManager {

    private HashMap<Class<?>, Renderer<?>> renderers;

    public void registerRenderer(Class<?> objclass, Renderer<?> renderer) {
        this.renderers.put(objclass, renderer);
    }

    public void render(Graphics2D g, Object object) {
        Class<?> objclass = object.getClass();
        if(this.renderers.get(objclass) != null) {
            this.renderers.get(objclass).render(g, object); 
        }
    }

}
```

using this object :

```
package com.Arsleust.DayumCorp.DayumEngine.Ressource;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public abstract class Renderer<T> {

    public abstract void init();

    public abstract void render(Graphics2D g, T object);

}
```

but `this.renderers.get(objclass).render(g, object);` makes an error, and Eclipse asks me to create a new method or to change the `Renderer.render` method's argument type `T` to `Object`.

Somehow I have to cast to that `T` generic type the `object` without know what type it is...
I'm getting really confused so i'm asking your help to see it more clearly.

Comment: Initialize renderes map first

Comment: @jw23 preferred to remove that part since it wasn't important for you, but don't worry i initialize my vars ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a `Renderer<?>` which means you have a `Renderer` of an unknown type.  i.e. you can get an element of this type as it will be an `Object` but you cannot pass an element of this type because you don't know what it is. i.e. the compiler cannot be sure it is right.

What you need to do is handle the type checking yourself and the compiler will complain about this because it can't check for you here.

```
public class RessourceManager {

    private final Map<Class, Renderer> renderers;

    public <T> void registerRenderer(Class<T> objclass, Renderer<T> renderer) {
        this.renderers.put(objclass, renderer);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void render(Graphics2D g, Object object) {
        Class objclass = object.getClass();
        if(this.renderers.get(objclass) != null) {
            this.renderers.get(objclass).render(g, object); 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Works perfectly ! I get unchecked and rawtypes warnings, but it should be ok. Thanks !

Comment: @Arsleust try moving the @`SuppressWarnings` annotation to the start of the class. Eclipse is 99% standard but has a few quirks. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Damn the generics, full speed ahead!

```
((Renderer) renderers.get(objclass)).render(g, object);
```

Cast the generic `Renderer<?>` to just a `Renderer`. It's breaking the generic type system, but it should be safe. You've made sure of that.

Comment: It suppress the errors but I get unchecked and rawtypes warnings... should be enough thought, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RessourceManager {

    private HashMap<Class<?>, Renderer<?>> renderers;

    public <V> void registerRenderer(Class<V> objclass, Renderer<V> renderer) {
        this.renderers.put(objclass, renderer);
    }

    public <V> void render(Graphics2D g, V object) {
        Class<?> objclass = object.getClass();
        if(this.renderers.get(objclass) != null) {
            ((Renderer<V>)this.renderers.get(objclass)).render(g, object);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't cast straight from `Renderer<?>` to `Renderer<V>` you need to cast `(Renderer)` in between. :P

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Why you think so?

Comment: The compiler doesn't allow you to cast from one generic type to an incompatible generic type.  You have to use type erasure to fool the compiler.

Comment: But those types are compatible, you check first if `renderer` was registered for object of type `V`. Try to run this code, it works fine.

Comment: You are right!  It reports a warning, not an error.